# Boundary Conditions for dielectric-conductor interface

Tags: electricity

I have been given a college assignment and there is this objective type question which asks for a boundary condition that is not satisfied by the dielectric-conductor interface. The following options are given;

1. $$ E_{t1} = E_{t2} $$
2. $$ D_{n1} = 0 $$
3. $$ H_{t1} = H_{t2} $$
4. $$ B_{n1} = B_{n2} $$

Where $$ E_{ti} $$ is tangential component of the electric field in the ith medium and $$H_{ti}$$ is the tangential component of the magnetic field intensity in the ith medium.

$$ D_{n1} $$ is the normal component of the electric flux density in medium one and $$ B_{ni} $$ is the normal component of the magnetic field in medium i.

Medium 1 is dielectric and medium 2 is conductor here.

I think that second option is correct because in conductor there is always some free charge, thus;
$$ D_{n1} = \rho_{s}$$.

Am I correct??
Please help!!

Comment: You might be better on the physics board. I think most engineers don't like to drop below circuit theory, I know I don't.

Comment: I just want to know if I am correct. Please help.

Comment: I am trying to help. I notice you have no replies, and I'm the only comment. This means you're on the wrong board. Try the [physics stack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), they do field theory. Personally, as an engineer, I happily left all that field theory behind when I left university, never to open my lecture notes again. I was never all that good at it anyway!